# How to set inverse gradient in a single row

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I have fixed a similar problems with diagonal gradient.
Now it's difficult with linear.

I was able to create a gradiet with a cross

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 40%,#f00 50%,transparent 60%), 
            linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 20%,#f00 50%,#fff 80%);
```

I can't create a gradient that have in the left half a gradient to bottom WHITE-RED and in the right half an inverse gradient RED-WHITE.

The below is the way I had tried to create it:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%,#ff0 100%), 
            linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%,#f00 100%);
```

But the yellow part is full! How can I fix this situation?

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: a runnable code snippet (e.g. jsfiddle) might be helpful

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I don't know it. Only with css isn't possible?

Comment: Using a service like jsfiddle or codepen you can provide a minimal running example that is easy to edit and for others easy to build upon.

Comment: Also an image done in Photoshop or Gimp showing what you want to get would be helpful too. As it stands I must admit I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I added a link with the image that I want. I do it with paint

Comment: Ah okay. How about having two DIVs left and right with the respective gradients?

Comment: It is my last chance. Because I have different css but the same html for different situations. If it is possible I wouldn't modify html. Is it possible?

Comment: @Harry If you see the answer of cedric he created an image with snippet

Comment: @Harvester Yes, I did see and had added an answer with a way to create it using single element + background rule also. I was able to see the image on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much possible to achieve this using a single element and a single background rule. Just give each of the gradients 50% size of the container in the X-axis, position one gradient on the left side and the other on right side using `background-position` and stop the gradient from repeating by setting the value for `background-repeat` as `no-repeat`.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red 10%, yellow 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, red 10%, yellow 50%);
  /* background-size: 50% 100%; Ideally this should be enough but it leaves a white line in the middle in snippet for some reason and so use below setting */
  background-size: 50% 100%, calc(50% + 1px) 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0%, 100% 0%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Yes! it works correctely! Just a thing (if it's possible, if not I however set you as correct answer): is it possible to made a grandient transition also between the two half part?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware you could match multiple backgrounds across multiple rules, nice.

Comment: @Harry I'm very sorry but I wasn't able to create an image. However if we call the first yellow A, the first red B (this is the first row). The second row have C (that is red) and D that is yellow. Well, I have a gradient to pass from A to C, I have a gradient to pass from B to D. Is it possible have also another gradient to pass from A to B and from C to D?

Comment: @Harvester: Nope that would be almost impossible to achieve even with multiple elements because of how the intermediate states would be. For example the top on left is yellow, top on right is red and we can smoothly transition between these two but what about the middle area on both the sides? They are both in between colors and so you can't transition much there.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: It is possible with one `background`, see [Harry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34589701/1090166).*

<strike>It's not directly possible with a single `background` rule on your element, but</strike> you can utilize the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0%, #ff0 100%);
}
div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red 0%, #ff0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: theoretically I need to a gradient also in linear to right gradient. But I create the image with paint.

Comment: And my div is header. This code doesn't work unfortunely

Comment: Harvester, change 'div' in his code to 'header' and it will work